# My phone has an error when I want to delete drafts, what should I do?

Tags: sms, htc-wildfire-s

So, here's the problem: when I want to delete drafts from HTC Wildfire S, I go to drafts and press the three-line-button, which always offers more options. It says "Delete drafts". I press that and it says that there's an error and that I should either force close everything, or report it to HTC. I can delete drafts by opening them and selecting discard from the menu, but I don't want to do that every time, and the lag is just irritating.

What should I do? Does someone have the same problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean 'draft' txt messages.

Try this:

> Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > Select the Messaging App
>
> Choose 'Clear Data' and also 'Clear Cache'.

If not you could also factory reset the phone.

Otherwise report it to [HTC support](http://www.htc.com/uk/help/)

Comment: Note that this will delete ALL text messages, sent, received and drafts.